Linux Off-path ICMP Fragmentation Needed Injection Attack to quic-go library
I was looking at CVE-2024-53259, where an attacker can inject ICMP Fragmentation Needed message to a host with QUIC connection using quic-go library. The cause is quic-go setting IP_PMTUDISC_DO socket option when probing its path mtu.
What I don't really get is while the CVE page basically says the kernel receives the attacker's ICMP packet and updates the path mtu, it seems like Linux kernel handles packet separately by dst ip and src ip for received ICMP error, building 'flow key' (I'm looking at ipv4_sk_update_pmtu func):
void ipv4_sk_update_pmtu(struct sk_buff *skb, struct sock *sk, u32 mtu)
{
    const struct iphdr *iph = (const struct iphdr *)skb->data;
    struct flowi4 fl4;
    struct rtable *rt;
    struct dst_entry *odst = NULL;
    bool new = false;
    struct net *net = sock_net(sk);

    bh_lock_sock(sk);

    if (!ip_sk_accept_pmtu(sk))
        goto out;

    odst = sk_dst_get(sk);

    if (sock_owned_by_user(sk) || !odst) {
        __ipv4_sk_update_pmtu(skb, sk, mtu);
        goto out;
    }
    // this function calls flowi4_init_output inside, which takes src/dst addr as arguments
    __build_flow_key(net, &fl4, sk, iph, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    rt = dst_rtable(odst);
    if (odst->obsolete && !odst->ops->check(odst, 0)) {
        rt = ip_route_output_flow(sock_net(sk), &fl4, sk);
        if (IS_ERR(rt))
            goto out;

        new = true;
    }
    ...
}

If packets are handled based on their src/dst address, attacker's packet should not interrupt existing connection because the packet has different source IP address. Why is this kind of attack available?
thanks in advance

Because the DHCP RFCs say we should accept path MTU updates from anyone.
The alternative would be to only accept PMTU updates from nodes along the path, which can change with each packet.
Consider the overhead in populating and maintaining a list of all the nodes along the path from here to there, who are allowed to update PMTU, for each TCP/IP packet!
You can detect nodes along the path by sending a packet from here to there, with the TTL (time-to-live) field set to 1, and record the host that returned a "Packet expired" error, then set the TTL to 2, 3, ... until you get a response from the actual destination. And, this path is allowed to change with the next packet you send.
